# Select SUM from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sum

I keep getting the wrong sum value when I join 3 tables.
Here is a pic of the ERD of the table:

[image]

(Original here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18794525/AUG%207%20DUMP%20STAN.png )

Here is the query:

```
select SUM(gpCutBody.actualQty) as cutQty   , SUM(gpSewBody.quantity) as sewQty
from jobOrder
inner join gpCutHead on gpCutHead.joNum = jobOrder.joNum
inner join gpSewHead on gpSewHead.joNum = jobOrder.joNum
inner join gpCutBody on gpCutBody.gpCutID = gpCutHead.gpCutID
inner join gpSewBody on gpSewBody.gpSewID = gpSewHead.gpSewID
```

Comment: In what way is it wrong? What should it be instead? It would be helpful if you could show what data you have your tables and what the correct result should be.

Answer (score 4):

If you are *only* interested in the quantities of cuts and sews for *all* orders, the simplest way to do it would be like this:

```
select (select SUM(gpCutBody.actualQty) from gpCutBody) as cutQty, 
       (select SUM(gpSewBody.quantity) from gpSewBody) as sewQty
```

(This assumes that cuts and sews will always have associated job orders.)

If you want to see a breakdown of cuts and sews by job order, something like this might be preferable:

```
select joNum, SUM(actualQty) as cutQty, SUM(quantity) as sewQty
from (select joNum, actualQty, 0 as quantity
      from gpCutBody
      union all
      select joNum, 0 as actualQty, quantity
      from gpSewBody) sc
group by joNum
```

Answer (score 3):

Mark's approach is a good one.  I want to suggest the alternative of doing the group by's before the union, simply because this can be a more general approach for summing along multiple dimensions.

Your problem is that you have two dimensions that you want to sum along, and you are getting a cross product of the values in the join.

```
select joNum, act.quantity as ActualQty, q.quantity as Quantity
from (select joNum, sum(actualQty) as quantity
      from gpCutBody
      group by joNum
     ) act full outer join
     (select joNum, sum(quantity) as quantity
      from gpSewBody
      group by joNum
     ) q
     on act.joNum = q.joNum
```

(I have kept Mark's assumption that doing this by joNum is the desired output.)